# Mysql where subquery performance

Tags: mysql, subquery, where-clause

So I have a problem with this query

```
SELECT e.entreprise, e.entreid, e.chargee, e.date, e.tel, e.email, e.adresse, e.ville,
e.codepostal, e.fax, e.accronyme, GROUP_CONCAT(c.nom, c.prenom, c.email separator ',') as keywords 
FROM contacts as c
LEFT JOIN entreprise as e ON e.entreid=c.contactid
LEFT JOIN metas as m ON e.entreid=m.elem_id
WHERE  e.entreid !=1 AND e.actif!='inactif' 
     AND ((m.meta_key='type_entreprise' 
     AND m.meta_value REGEXP '(client)') 
     OR m.meta_key is null) 
GROUP BY e.entreid  ORDER BY e.entreprise ASC
```

This query is suppose to return me all the entreprise that are client... The problem is that the field that make it a client is in the metas table(LIKE 9000 entries and many for the entreprise) and when I run this query it take about 70 second to perform it.

If anyone can help it would be appreciated

Comment: Have I understood it correctly that the metas table is "remote" and that it takes too long to `INNER JOIN` it with entreprise? In that case, what about preselecting a collection of `element_id`s from metas into a temporary tabe and then joining that with the entreprise table?

Comment: Do you have an index on elem_id on the metas table? Could you run and EXPLAIN for this query and post the results? Rather than checking the details from meta in the WHERE clause and then also having to check for NULL it might be worth just doing the check in the ON clause (which will avoid the need for an OR when checking for NULL).

Comment: This is the Explain (Sorry for the formatting): id  select_type  table  type  possible_keys  key  key_len  ref  rows  Extra
1  SIMPLE  c  ALL  PRIMARY  NULL NULL NULL 3425  Using temporary; Using filesort
1  SIMPLE  e  eq_ref  PRIMARY,actif  PRIMARY  3  bang-server.c.contactid  1  Using where
1  SIMPLE  m  ALL  elem_id  NULL NULL NULL 7729  Using where

Comment: I have index on elem_id, meta_key and elem_type in the metas table. Can you guy give me some example of your suggestions?

Comment: Why are you using `REGEXP` when it seems `LIKE('%client%')` will do?

Comment: @MikeBrant - tend to agree although neither is going to be efficient

Answer (score 0):

Looking at your EXPLAIN it hasn't used any indexes on the metas table.

Try a composite key on 2 columns, both meta_key AND elem_id

As to the query, try it like this:-

```
SELECT e.entreprise, e.entreid, e.chargee, e.date, e.tel, e.email, e.adresse, e.ville,
e.codepostal, e.fax, e.accronyme, GROUP_CONCAT(c.nom, c.prenom, c.email separator ',') as keywords 
FROM contacts as c
LEFT JOIN entreprise as e 
ON e.entreid = c.contactid
LEFT JOIN metas as m 
ON e.entreid = m.elem_id
AND m.meta_key = 'type_entreprise' 
AND m.meta_value REGEXP '(client)' 
WHERE e.entreid !=1 
AND e.actif!='inactif' 
GROUP BY e.entreid  
ORDER BY e.entreprise ASC
```

Looking at that it doesn't seem logical to have a LEFT JOIN against entreprise, given that most of the fields you are bring back are from that table. If you must always have a record on entreprise then change it to an INNER JOIN which should allow it to use the indexes on that, and then from there onto contacts:-

```
SELECT e.entreprise, e.entreid, e.chargee, e.date, e.tel, e.email, e.adresse, e.ville,
e.codepostal, e.fax, e.accronyme, GROUP_CONCAT(c.nom, c.prenom, c.email separator ',') as keywords 
FROM entreprise as e 
INNER JOIN contacts as c
ON e.entreid = c.contactid
LEFT JOIN metas as m 
ON e.entreid = m.elem_id
AND m.meta_key = 'type_entreprise' 
AND m.meta_value REGEXP '(client)' 
WHERE e.entreid !=1 
AND e.actif!='inactif' 
GROUP BY e.entreid  
ORDER BY e.entreprise ASC
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok so using comment from cars10, I've been able to reduce the query time from 70 to 2.2 second. I don't know if it's the right thing to do but it's seems to work.

This is the new query

```
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE temptable AS (SELECT m.meta_value, m.elem_id FROM metas as m WHERE m.meta_key='type_entreprise');
SELECT e.entreprise, e.entreid, e.chargee, e.date, e.tel, e.email, e.adresse, e.ville,     e.codepostal, e.fax, e.accronyme, GROUP_CONCAT( c.nom, c.prenom, c.email
SEPARATOR ',' ) AS keywords, temp.meta_value
FROM contacts AS c
LEFT JOIN entreprise AS e ON e.entreid = c.contactid
LEFT JOIN temptable AS temp ON temp.elem_id = e.entreid
WHERE e.entreid !=1
AND e.actif != 'inactif'
AND temp.meta_value REGEXP "(client)"
GROUP BY e.entreid
ORDER BY e.entreprise ASC
```

Comment: You are checking against meta_value in your query. This will exclude any record that isn't found on temptable. As such usng a LEFT JOIN is wasteful. Swap it to an INNER JOIN. You may as well also put this check in the temp table create. Also (and related to the 2nd query I suggested above), do you really want to try and bring back a list of contacts who have no enterprise record? Doesn't seem logical for a list of enterprises, but if these contacts are common it could also potentially bring back a massive number of contacts